# jQuery: How to change multiple form attributes before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to manipulate form submission with couple of submit buttons using jQuery. The code goes like this:

```
    <form id="cf" action="" method="POST" target="">
        <button id="preview">Preview</button>
        <button name="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#preview").on("click",function(e) {  
            $(this).attr('name','submit');
            e.preventDefault();         
            $("#cf").attr({
                    'action':'/preview/',
                    'target':'_blank'
                }).submit();
        });
    </script>
```

Changing attribute values seemed to work when "Preview" button is clicked, but it doesn't submit. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You form's `id` should be `"cf"`, not `"#cf"`. The `#` in `$("#cf")` means "select by the id *following* the `#`".

Comment: Your button is  overwriting `form.submit` because it's named `submit`, change the name of the button, and it will work.

Comment: @Paul Roub Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Every form has a submit function attached to it, it's referenced as `form.submit`.

When you name something inside the form `submit` it too is attached to the form, and it overwrites the native `form.submit` so the form can no longer be submitted with the submit function.

Rename the button to anything other than `submit`, and remove the line that sets the name to `submit`

```
<form id="cf" action="" method="POST" target="">
    <button id="preview">Preview</button>
    <button name="my_submit" id="my_submit">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#preview").on("click",function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();         

        $("#cf").attr({
                'action':'/preview/',
                'target':'_blank'
        }).submit();
    });
</script>
```